# What exactly is three phase power?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current, power

What is [three phase power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power)? How does it differ from normal AC current?

Comment: What exactly is it about the wikipedia article that you don't understand?

Comment: The fact that you claim the existence of "normal" AC suggests you should spend some time learning about current, voltage, sine functions, and phase relations.

Comment: But three phase is normal....

Answer (score 2):

Three phase power means that the power is delivered as three separate voltages, each sine waves 1/3 cycle out of phase with each other.  This is the least number of phases that have both these properties:

The instantaneous delivered power into a resistive load is constant (doesn't vary over a cycle).

The average of all voltages is always 0.